# gamma function type complex integral estimation?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, gamma-function

Is there any way to compute or estimate the following integrals? Surely this type of thing must be known, but Wolfram and other online integrators are giving me either useless or zero information:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}x^n e^{\pm ix}dx$$ where $n\geq1$ is an integer.

Comment: If it were $f:\ \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, we could use comparison.

Comment: You can compute the integral via integration by parts, or by expanding the exponential into its power series and integrating termwise. Apparently, those are not the type of result you want, so can you clarify what type of result/estimate you want?

Comment: I suppose I am mainly looking for a numerical estimation of really any kind. Do you recommend parts or expansion for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integration by parts gives
$$
\begin{align}
a_n
&=\int_0^{2\pi}x^ne^{ix}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=-i(2\pi)^n+in\int_0^{2\pi}x^{n-1}e^{ix}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\[6pt]
&=-i(2\pi)^n+ina_{n-1}\tag{3}\\[6pt]
&=i^nn!\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-i2\pi)^k}{ik!}\tag{4}\\
&=n!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^{n+k}(-i)^{k-1}}{(n+k)!}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: define $a_n$
$(2)$: integrate by parts
$(3)$: rewrite $(2)$ in terms of $(1)$
$(4)$: solve the recursion from $(3)$
$(5)$: use $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-i2\pi)^k}{k!}=e^{-2\pi i}-1=0$

The real and imaginary parts of $(5)$ give the asymptotic expansions
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}x^n\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{(2\pi)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{(2\pi)^{n+3}}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+O\left(\frac{(2\pi)^n}{n^5}\right)\tag{6}
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}x^n\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{(2\pi)^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{(2\pi)^{n+4}}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}+O\left(\frac{(2\pi)^n}{n^6}\right)\tag{7}
$$

Comment: I also got the leading term of (6) using the approximation-to-the-identity argument, but I never expected that such a precise expansion can be obtained by a simple and elegant computation. (+1)

Comment: It is possible due to the fact that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-i2\pi)^k}{k!}=e^{-2\pi i}-1=0$$

Comment: @robjohn, elegant!

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I hadn't realized (5), or life would have been a little easier!

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitution $\mp ix=u$ and $\mp idx=du$.

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}x^ne^{\pm ix}dx&=\pm i\int_0^{\mp2\pi i}(\mp iu)^ne^{-u}du\\
&=-(\mp i)^{n+1}\int_0^{\mp2\pi i}u^ne^{-u}du\\
&=-(\mp i)^{n+1}\gamma(n+1,\mp2\pi i)
\end{align}$$

where $\gamma(n,x)$ is the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

---

An example of an approximation:

$$\gamma(n,x)\approx x^n\left(\frac1n-\frac x{1!(n+1)}+\frac{x^2}{2!(n+2)}-\dots+\frac{(-x)^k}{k!(n+k)}\right)$$

for very large $k$.

Comment: Sure, but how do I then estimate the incomplete gamma function given?

Comment: @JohnnyApple You may find everything in the link I will provide in my answer momentarily.

Comment: I have been to the wiki page on this function. Where is there information on estimation?

Comment: @JohnnyApple You may have found many expansion of the lower incomplete gamma function, which provide approximations.

Comment: Gamma functions, including the upper and lower incomplete gamma functions, can be evaluated via SymPy (http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#module-sympy.functions.special.gamma_functions), which can be used via an online version or of course you can download the Python package.

Comment: What is $s$ in the asymptotic expansion?

Comment: Thank you for your replies!

Comment: @robjohn 'tis the struggles of my changing of variables when copy/pasting.

Answer (score 0):

We can write
$$
\int_{\,x\, = \,0}^{\,2\pi } {x^{\,n\,} e^{\, \pm \,i\,x} \,dx}  = \int_{\,x\, = \,0}^{\,2\pi } {x^{\,n\,} \left( {\cos x \pm \,i\sin x} \right)\,dx} 
$$
And we can start and compute the integral by parts 
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \int_{\,x\, = \,0}^{\,2\pi } {x^{\,n\,} \cos x\,dx}  = \int_{\,x\, = \,0}^{\,2\pi } {x^{\,n\,} d\left( {\sin x} \right)}  = \left. {\left( {x^{\,n\,} \sin x} \right)} \right|_{\,x\, = \,0}^{\,2\pi }  - n\int_{\,x\, = \,0}^{\,2\pi } {x^{\,n - 1\,} \sin x\,dx}  =  \hfill \\
   =  - n\int_{\,x\, = \,0}^{\,2\pi } {x^{\,n - 1\,} \sin x\,dx}  \hfill \\
  \int_{\,x\, = \,0}^{\,2\pi } {x^{\,n\,} \sin x\,dx}  =  - \int_{\,x\, = \,0}^{\,2\pi } {x^{\,n\,} d\left( {\cos x} \right)}  = \left. {\left( { - x^{\,n\,} \cos x} \right)} \right|_{\,x\, = \,0}^{\,2\pi }  + n\int_{\,x\, = \,0}^{\,2\pi } {x^{\,n - 1\,} \cos x\,dx}  =  \hfill \\
   = \left[ {0 = n} \right] - 2^{\,n\,} \pi ^{\,n\,}  + n\int_{\,x\, = \,0}^{\,2\pi } {x^{\,n - 1\,} \cos x\,dx}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
which translates into a double FDE.

Now, if your scope is to calculate the integrals on a computer, then you can use this result iteratively.